# Easy cm accurate GNSS / GPS for rover with base station?

Tags: mobile-robot, gps, precise-positioning

I am trying to design a system to measure snow depth during snow production on a tiny ski resort in Denmark.

My idea is simple: Drive a rover over the ground during the summer, and obtain height data with lat long. During snow production, drive it again, and compare the height data with the height data from the summer. Provide snow depths to the people working, such that snowproduction can be optimal.

However, I need 1-2 cm accuracy in the vertical direction for this to be useful - and my readings have led me to believe I need to use a base station and RTK to get the needed accuracy. I expect the rover speed to be no more than 2 m/s (although higher speeds would be great, of course). I will (try to) design and build the rover to fit the project, so weight is not an issue, and I can probably add pretty large batteries to it. (The rover will need to reliably climb 30% snow covered inclines, and be able to either use GSM for communications or be able to communicate at least 500 meters using radio. It will also need to be robust enough to be covered in artificial snow during operation, etc.)

I have read a lot of blog posts and whatnot, that wants to use RTK lib and low cost receivers, but this question : [Low-cost centimeter accurate satellite positioning (GNSS/GPS)](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/low-cost-centimeter-accurate-satellite-positioning-gnss-gps) - seems to suggest that this product : http://navspark.mybigcommerce.com/ns-hp-gl-gps-glonass-rtk-receiver/ - is sort of the solution to all my problems, wrapped in a simple package? (Its sort of cheap too, I think, at least not very expensive.) The question is from 2014 though, and it seems a lot have happened in this space since then?

I am sorry to ask a question that may be somewhat opinion based, but would a solution based on two NH-HP-GL be suitable for this project? (Denmark is in Europe, so I reckon it would have to be the GL model, right?). If yes, any recommendations on models, given the target speed of 2 m/s?

Also: I have not decided on what computing platform to base the rover on - any comments on Arduino or Raspberry (or entirely different) for this project? The biggest unknown in this project to me is the high accuracy GNSS, but radio communication from the base station to the rover is part of this and something I have not done with neither Arduino or Raspberry - so thanks for helping out.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mads Bondo Dydensborg, but I'm afraid that questions which ask about the Pros/cons or Advantages/disadvantages are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for me, actually.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't help on this occasion. When you come to build your robot, we would love to help out with specific problems you come across though. Also, you might find there are some useful questions over on [dsp.se] about GPS accuracy. Best of luck with your project. I'd certainly like to hear how you get on over on [chat], when you have [chat privileges](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).